# Finding equivalent of point from inside of 2D triangle on deformed 3D one

Tags: c++, geometry

So I am making that simple system, that makes path in 2D triangle, but then I have to find its equivalent on 3D one. That would not be as much of a hassle, if said triangle would not be from texture, meaning that it may have different angles etc. from the one marked on .png file. Finding traingle points is one thing, but I also need points inside said triangle with the same relative distances from all corners. I have no idea how to do it. Is there any simple way to do it?

EDIT:
To elaborate a little:
I have 3D mesh on which there is a texture applied in external program (e.g. blender). Mesh's triangle's geometry may vary while applying (the whole point of process of texture mapping, to be able to adjust shape and size to image), but the distances describing points on image are set to certain vertices on model. I load it in my program, read the coords of triangles, as well as coords of texture in range (0, 1) for each vertex. Now I load texture file, extract needed information (tool paths based on colors on geometry), but the paths I generate still are 2D and in texture image scale. I need to scale it to real size (points of the triangle) and keep the found paths on surface of such model, thus I need to find points that are in the same distance from each corner and are on a plane which triangle is.

EDIT2:
The path that I have in 2D comes from gradual scalling down of the outline of shape detected on texture. I turn the image to binary, get outline and scale down several times to get this concentric paths. It is described in image coordinate space, because it is directly from image. Now this concentric path needs to be converted to mesh's coordinates.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you're trying to do here? How are these textures defined? Is the goal to map the flat contour onto the textured triangle? If so, what format do you have the data in, and what's the expected result format? (I imagine that, if you can include pictures and sample code for what you have now, this would be a bit easier to follow.)

Comment: Can you express your path in barycentric coordinates? Then mapping to the triangle positions in 3D space would be very easy. Btw, the same relative distance from all corners is probably not what you want. A point that was previously inside the triangle might appear outside if the triangle is heavily deformed.

Comment: @templatetypedef Added more detailed desctiption

Comment: @NicoSchertler Barycentric is nice option, but your point about heavy deformation is ideed true. But I have no other idea to 'export' paths to mesh's triangle

Comment: Maybe you could add to your question where your path is coming from and how it is defined. I have similar problems as @templatetypedef to understand your question. Images would help a lot.